Approximate Set Intersection datastructure
I'm working on a project involving set-like data structures. For one of the algorithms I am using that does a  merge-like operation on two of these structures I can take a very big shortcut if I know in advance that the two sets are disjoint.
I'm not an expert on probabilistic datastructures but I am trying to find a bloomfilter-like data structure that will let me add some metadata to my 'sets' that let me say either:

these two sets definitely have an empty intersection
These two sets may have a non-empty intersection.

The goal is to permit a quick check and decide which version of the algorithm to use.
Additionally, I'm looking for this structure to be mergeable (If I union two sets, I'd like a quick way to union the associated data structures without fully recomputing the structure for the new set).
It strikes me that a bloom-filter is almost what I want because if I have a bloom-filter using 1 hash function, I can boolean-AND two filters and if this is 0, then it's guaranteed to have 0 intersection. But using 2 or more hash functions give a possibility of non-zero intersections!
Another alternative I've been considering is an extension where I take start with something like a bloomfilter and 1 hash function (as above) and instead of recording a single bit at index k, I  insert a fingerprint (similar to a cuckoo filter), by taking an  OR of the existing fingerprint at this location - which is possibly zero -  and the newly inserted fingerprint.
Then to take an intersection I can first do a boolean-AND on the Index (to see which 'buckets' are occupied), and from there, I can AND the fingerprints. If the two data-structures do not share an element then this should result in a 0 value.
This seems maybe better(?) but I haven't analyzed it. But, it feels space-inefficient and I'm not really sure this is any 'good'?
I've also looked at MinHash and HyperLogLog, and while close, these don't see quite what I'm looking for (I want a definite answer in one direction !)
I'm not really sure what the terminology to lookup for this sort of structure is and I was hoping  someone here who's much smarter than me could help point me in the correct direction of search terms   or papers that might help here.

(If the domain of the elements is ordered, exploit min&max.)
